# „[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials“

Tags: ros, beginner-tutorials, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm absolutely new to ROS (and quite new to LINUX).

I installed ROS JADE on Ubuntu 14.04 and did the first three tutorials. In the Tutorial: „Creating a ROS Package“ I'm encountering an error. The command:

```
rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
```

gives:

```
[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials
```

My catkin structure is:

```
hpe@hpe-P5Q-PRO:~/catkin_ws$ ls
beginner_tutorials  build  devel  src
```

I tried to add the workspace with:

```
 $ . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

and

```
hpe@hpe-P5Q-PRO:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
```

But with same result.

Any idea what is wrong with my setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222344/%E2%80%9E%5Brospack%5D-error:-no-such-package-beginner_tutorials%E2%80%9C/) by [vitus](https://answers.ros.org/users/25306/vitus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-11**:
For future questions: if you use the `101010` button on the formatting toolbar (*Preformatted text*) it will make console copy/pastes much easier to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My catkin structure is:

> ```
> hpe@hpe-P5Q-PRO:~/catkin_ws$ ls
> ```

```
beginner_tutorials  build  devel  src
```

Packages (such as `beginner_tutorials`) should be placed *inside* the `src` directory. By default, that is the only place `catkin` will look for them, and if you build your workspace as it is right now, no packages should be found (`catkin_make` probably finished rather quickly, and without compiling any files).

Helpful diagram (from [here](https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/articles/202926439-ROS-Workspace-structure)):

[image: Typical ROS workspace layout]

This layout is also suggested / recommended in the *Creating a ROS Package* tutorial, in the [Packages in a catkin Workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage#ROS.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-catkin.2BAC8-CreatingPackage.Packages_in_a_catkin_Workspace) section. Perhaps you've missed the first sentence under *Creating a catkin Package*:

> First change to *the source space* directory of the catkin workspace you created in the [Creating a Workspace for catkin tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) [..]

See if after moving the `beginner_tutorials` dir, rebuilding your workspace and re-sourcing `devel/setup.bash` the `rospack find ..` command succeeds.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vitus](https://answers.ros.org/users/25306/vitus/) on 2015-12-11**:
Yes indeed. It works now.
Thank you for your assistance.

**Comment by [Face](https://answers.ros.org/users/57052/face/) on 2022-10-14**:
Good answer, really hits the spot.I was going to answer it  but you did such a good job I had to say so. I think this ticket can be closed.